# How can I get data from firebase cloud?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of data linked like this

> users => doc(Current user) => last_msg => doc => some data

I am not getting the data, I received null every time.

```
  _fireStore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(currentUserId)
        .collection("lase_msg")
        .doc("cHxIpGAoxhkRZYo9EjgX")
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      userlstMsg = documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    });
```

this is my code and i am receiving null but i should have this data

```
cHxIpGAoxhkRZYo9EjgX_msg
"fffffffff"
cHxIpGAoxhkRZYo9EjgX_time
October 27, 2022 at 9:26:05 PM UTC+6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a typo `lase_msg` will be `last_msg`

```dart
_fireStore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(currentUserId)
        .collection("last_msg") //here
        .doc("cHxIpGAoxhkRZYo9EjgX")
        .get()
```

Comment: yeah that's my type mistake it's last_msg